# Search widget will search everything in the site, how to limit to only search gallery name

Tags: customization, widgets, search

I am using the default search widget in sidebar, the problem is , it will search every text in the site.

I would like to make different search widget, e.g. one search widget for search gallery name only, another search widget for search the blog title.

Any way to achieve that? Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is "gallery name"?

Comment: in fact it is a post, where  'post_type' => 'dt_galleries', thanks

Comment: This should work out https://gist.github.com/galengidman/8b84770a2dcc9abb8bfe.